# Duplicating a Quote in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Im having some issue when comming back (using back button) from a payment gateway, we do a quote restore:

$this->checkoutSession->restoreQuote();

But this works good having the same cart, but we would like to actually not restore the quote insteade creating a new one coping this one. As if we restore the quote we get the same information of extra attributes we use for the order.

How can i create a new quote that copy the same products as the other one?

thanks

Comment: Your question has the answer, Just adding product to new cart automatically.